# How the following Inverse Fourier Transform is obtained.

Tags: random-variables, fourier-transform, signal-processing

In one of the numerical, I came across the following power spectral density (PSD):

$S_{Y}(f) = 2; |f| < 2$ and $S_{Y}(f) = 0; \text{otherwise}$.

Its autocorrelation is given as $R_{Y}(\tau) = 8 \text{Sinc}(4\tau)$ ---(1)

I know that autocorrelation is inverse Fourier transform of PSD, but I am not getting how the autocorrelation in equation (1) is obtained.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try computing the integral directly?

Comment: Thank u so much sir for ur reply... I tried upto following step: $R_{Y} (\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}S_{Y}(f) e^{j2\pi f \tau} \text{d}f = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}2 e^{j2\pi f \tau} \text{d}f $. I am not getting what limits should I put now in place of $-\infty$ and $+ \infty$.

Comment: I got the answer when I substituted the limits as -2 to +2 . But I am still not getting why the limits should be from -2 to +2. Basically my confusion is due to |f| < 2.

Comment: $\vert f\vert$ is absolute value of $f$ , e.g. $|-1|=1$,  $|f|<2$ is same as $−2<f<2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because
$$S_{Y}(f) =\begin{cases}
    2&|f|<2\\
    0&f\le -2 \:or\: f \ge 2 
\end{cases}$$
we have
$$R_{Y} (\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}S_{Y}(f) e^{j2\pi f \tau} \text{d}f = \int_{-2}^{2}2 e^{j2\pi f \tau} \text{d}f=\left[\frac{e^{j2\pi f \tau}}{j\pi\tau}\right]^2_{-2}\\=\frac{e^{j4\pi\tau}-e^{-j4\pi\tau}}{j\pi\tau}=\frac{2\sin4\pi\tau}{\pi\tau}=\frac{8\sin4\pi\tau}{4\pi\tau}=8\;\text{sinc}\:(4\tau)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.... I had also got the answer, but not getting why we substitute the limit -2 to +2, basically getting doubt because of |f| < 2.

Comment: Because $S_{Y}(f)$ is nonzero only when $-2<f<2$, so the integral outside this region is always zero...

Comment: Yes ... That I also know...My basic doubt is how we are considering $|f| <2$ as $-2 < f < 2$....

Comment: What is your doubt? Isn't $|f|<2$ the same as $-2<f<2$, or are you thinking of $f$ as a complex number?

Comment: No ...I am not considering $f$ as complex. But I am not getting how $|f|<2$ is same as $-2 < f < 2$. Any way will ask new question regarding this doubt...